# filtering a df with special characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lambda

Hello everyone i have a df like below :-

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([
    {'0':'a:1','1':'b:2','2':'c:abc' },
    {'0':'a:2','1':'b:5','2':'c:afbc'}
])
```

[image]

I want to convert it into a df like below :-

[image]

I want to rename the column index with values `before :` and the values in the column should be anything `after :`

As of now i am doing it the hard way, first renaming and then removing characters from beginning :-

```
dff.rename(columns={'0': 'a', '1': 'b', '2': 'c',}, inplace=True)
dff['a'] = dff['a'].map(lambda x: str(x)[2:])
dff['b'] = dff['b'].map(lambda x: str(x)[2:])
dff['c'] = dff['c'].map(lambda x: str(x)[2:])
```

I want some help if there is any one liner or lambda function i can use as i am having more than 20 columns.

P.S - The 0,1,2 in the original data frame are column indexes. just for demonstration i have used them as column name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `stack` with `str.split` , then we working on the reshape

```
df.stack().str.split(':',expand=True).\
    set_index(0,append=True).\
      reset_index(level=1,drop=True)[1].\
        unstack()
Out[44]: 
0  a  b     c
0  1  2   abc
1  2  5  afbc
```

---

Using `crosstab`

```
s=df.reset_index().melt('index')
v=s.value.str.split(':')
pd.crosstab(index=s['index'],columns=v.str[0],values=v.str[1],aggfunc='first')
Out[78]: 
value  a  b     c
index            
0      1  2   abc
1      2  5  afbc
```

Comment: Agreed, this answer is useful.

Comment: @W-B your answer worked totally fine with my case and i have 98 columns and it worked in one go with all kinds of data types. I don't know who downvoted and why.

Answer (score 6):

#### list of dictionaries

```
pd.DataFrame([dict(x.split(':') for x in r) for r in df.values])

   a  b     c
0  1  2   abc
1  2  5  afbc
```

#### Alternative

```
pd.DataFrame([*df.apply(lambda r: dict(r.str.split(':').values), 1)])
```

---

In response to comment from OP

> the code doesnt work when the column names are more than one characters say aa or time like that. its only workign when the column names are like a, b ,c and not with aa, bbbb, cccccc – [ak333](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53486855/filtering-a-df-with-special-characters/53486960#comment93843686_53486960)

Consider the dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'0': 'aa:1', '1': 'bbb:2', '2': 'cccc:abc'},
    {'0': 'aa:2', '1': 'bbb:5', '2': 'cccc:afbc'}
])
df

      0      1          2
0  aa:1  bbb:2   cccc:abc
1  aa:2  bbb:5  cccc:afbc
```

the same solution results in

```
pd.DataFrame([dict(x.split(':') for x in r) for r in df.values])

  aa bbb  cccc
0  1   2   abc
1  2   5  afbc
```

Comment: the code doesnt work when the column names are more than one characters say aa or time like that. its only workign when the column names are like a, b ,c and not with aa, bbbb, cccccc

Comment: You sure?  This splits the string on `':'`.  Are you commenting on the wrong answer?  I've updated my post to demonstrate.

Comment: @piRSquared I think ak333 meant to comment on my answer.

Comment: Interesting how the `DataFrame` constructor works fine with a list of dicts but you need `from_records` when you want to pass a  `Series` of dicts.

Comment: Yes, thanks for that.  Reminded me of why I went with comprehension.

Comment: @piRSquared yes i tested it then. sorry i got a little occupied..its working fine now..thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 2):

`DataFrame.apply` lets you apply a function to each series your dataframe is made of. `Series.str` allows for vectorized string operations (and some other stuff) on the elements of a series.

Putting both together:

```
>>> df
     0    1       2
0  a:1  b:2   c:abc
1  a:2  b:5  c:afbc
>>> 
>>> df.apply(lambda col: col.str[2:])
   0  1     2
0  1  2   abc
1  2  5  afbc
```

edit: ok, I admit it's quite an ugly oneliner.

```
>>> df.apply(lambda col: col.str[2:]).rename(columns=dict(zip(df.columns, df.loc[0].str[:1])))
   a  b     c
0  1  2   abc
1  2  5  afbc
```

edit2:

well, if the parts before the `':'` can have more than one character:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda col: col.str.partition(':')[2]).rename(columns=dict(zip(df.columns, df.loc[0].str.partition(':')[0])))
   a  b     c
0  1  2   abc
1  2  5  afbc
```

I like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53486960/3620003) solution best.

Comment: @timegeb thanks for your answer but i can do that. I need a one liner which will also rename the column with anything before the : sign.   0,1,2 are column indexes here.

Comment: @ak333 I didnt see that renaming part. Give me a second.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way using regex, though I would still try reading the data in proper format.

```
df.columns = df.iloc[0].str.extract('(.*):', expand = False)
df.replace('.*:', '', regex = True, inplace = True)

a   b   c
0   1   2   abc
1   2   5   afbc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Create column names
df.columns=list(df[0:1].applymap(lambda x: x.split(':')[0]).iloc[0]) 

#applymap() - Apply a function to a Dataframe elementwise.
df=df.applymap(lambda x: x.split(':')[1])

df
   a  b     c
0  1  2   abc
1  2  5  afbc
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Code is fairly clear. There is no need of further annotations.